# Unable to integrate Fabric on latest Unity 2018.2

Tags: unity-game-engine, crashlytics, google-fabric

We have been using fabric for last one year on Unity to measure crash rates and to report retention numbers. Recently Unity has released a new version 2018.2, post which we are not able to integrate fabric on unity.

I think this is because of the new way that Unity has started building android project to take benefit of the latest advancement that android has made.

Is there a way by which we can integrate fabric on Unity 2018.2 or a later version.

Answer (score 0):

We just solve this by disabling and enabling crashlytics.

From Unity editor Fabric/Crashlytics/Disable Crashlystics than Fabric/Crashlytics/Enable Crashlystics.